# UseEffect is thrown when it shouldn't be

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use a useEffect in my React code which works fine at first but writing a search engine using a useState called "search" when setting its new value through an input onChange my useEffect is executed automatically again although it is never waiting changing my useState to "search", this is my code

```js
const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

useEffect(() => {
  pages();
}, [limitPage, page, products]);

const pages = () => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  getProducts(limitPage, page, search);
  getXlsProducts(100000, 1);
  const totalPages = Math.ceil(totalDocs / limitPage);
  const links = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
    links[i] = i;
  }
  setNumbers(links);

  setTotalDocs(products.products?.totalDocs);
  setTotalPages(products.products?.totalPages);
  setCurrentPage(products.products?.page);
  setNextPage(products.products?.hasNextPage);
  setPreviousPage(products.products?.hasPrevPage);
};
```

I need to use the button that calls the handleSearch() function in order to perform the search, but as soon as a change in the input automatically occurs, my useEffect is executed:

```jsx
<div>
  <input
    className="border-1 border-2 border-solid rounded border-slate-300"
    value={search}
    onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
  />
  <button onClick={() => handleSearch()}>
    <FiSearch />
  </button>
</div>
```

Here is the function to use when clicking on the button but it is never used because as soon as search changes value through the input it no longer gets executed:

```js
const handleSearch = () => {
  setLimitPage(10);
  setPage(1);
  getProducts(limitPage, page, search);
};
```

How can I avoid the automatic firing of my useEffect so that I can use my search function through the button? thanks.

Comment: Are you sure `products` is supposed to be in the dependency array?

Comment: It happens that products receive the results of the query from the API, so at the beginning it can contain 10 products and when doing a search now it can contain 5 products so it changes depending on the query

Comment: Sure, but setting products inside a `useEffect` that has a products dependency causes an infinite loop. What I'm saying is you need to re-run the query when *search* changes, not products.

Comment: Until now it has not created an infinite loop for me, I was reviewing the requests to my API as well as each request showing it on the console and it only calls once depending on the search. For now what I don't understand is why if the search value changes immediately my useEffect is executed without using the button

Comment: Not sure, but you should also keep in mind that changes to state do not happen immediately. Calling `setLimitPage(10)` is queued, and calling `getProducts(limitPage, page, search);` right after will use the old `limitPage` value.

Comment: Can you post the full code of the component?

Comment: Can you share the code for getProducts, getXlsProducts, these look suspicious.

Comment: Can you show the code of `getProducts` ? Does it contain an API call ?

Answer (score 7):

```
useEffect(() => {
  pages();
}, [limitPage, page, products]);
```

Dependencies in React's hooks use [**shallow comparison**](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/a8c9cb18b7e5d9eb3817272a1260f9f6b79815a2/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.new.js#L365).

As @ChrisG mentioned in the comment - "You have infinite loop". It's async loop because as you said, `getProducts` function request products from the server. So when you get a list of products from the server even if they semantically equal as already set you still create a new array with new reference. So `useEffect` triggered again because reference on products list has changed!

```
//triggered useEffect by first run
// when we create component and call `pages()`
useEffect(() => {
  pages();
}, [limitPage, page, products]);


const pages = () => {
  //Make a request to the server and set products list
  // like setProducts(response.products) this cause
  // create new array with new reference
  getProducts(limitPage, page, search);
  ...
}

//products === response.products // False because these are two different objects
// so we trigger useEffect again (returns to )
useEffect(() => {
  pages();
}, [limitPage, page, products]);
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I have understood , you want `getProducts()` to be called on the `first render` as well as whenever the state `limitPage and page` changes and whenever `Search` Button is pressed.

You already have `handleSearch` function for calling `getProducts()` that is triggering the API on the click of `Search` button,

```
const handleSearch = () => {
  setLimitPage(10);
  setPage(1);
   getProducts(limitPage, page, search);
};
```

In the handleSearch() as mentioned by @ChrisG in comment :- you need to take care of `limitPage` and `page` value as it will use the previous value here.

for calling API on `first render` and whenever the states `limitPage` and `page`changes, remove `products` dependency from `useEffect` and modify pages() function with the required statements:-

```
useEffect(() => {
   pages();
 }, [limitPage, page]);

const pages = () => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  getProducts(limitPage, page, search);
  getXlsProducts(100000, 1);
  const totalPages = Math.ceil(totalDocs / limitPage);
  const links = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
  links[i] = i;
 }
  setNumbers(links);

};
```

I saw several states that you want to update on the change of `products` state,
for that , you can have another `useEffect` with `products` dependency and a new method updating the required states:-

```
 useEffect(() => {
   updateStates();
 }, [products]);

const updateStates = () => {
  setTotalDocs(products.products?.totalDocs);
  setTotalPages(products.products?.totalPages);
  setCurrentPage(products.products?.page);
  setNextPage(products.products?.hasNextPage);
  setPreviousPage(products.products?.hasPrevPage);
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the **shallow comparison** as stated by @maksimr.
An alternative is to use class based components with `shouldComponentUpdate`:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    // if no products in current state, update when there are products in 
    // future state, or else remain.
    if(!this.state.products.length) {
        return nextState.products.length;
    }
    // update if there's a product in current state whose id
    // is not found in the next state's products
    return this.state.products.some((prod)=>(
        !nextState.products.find((p)=> (
            prod.id == p.id 
        )
    );
}
```